# how Name a Cell in google spreadheet and use by name on a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to declare a specific cell with a name, suppose, example B1 as "DolarValue", and reference in other cells by the name "DolarValue", let's say in cell C1 = value of "DolarValue" * content of B1 cell, let's assume that want a multiplication, how do you do that in Google Docs SpreadSheet ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the cell you want to name, open the Data menu, click Named ranges.

On the sidebar, click Add a range, type a name for your range and click Done.

Then, in the spreadsheet, you can use that name rather than the cell reference, eg:

`=DollarValue*A1`